# javascript: Unable to delete some elements of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/83m3B/

I want to delete some elements of an array by using `data-object-id` attribute.
But when I use it, the loop does not run as expected. It seems like it jumps over an element every time.

```
var banIds = ["111", "222", "333"];
function toggle_visibility(className) {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className),
    n = elements.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var e = elements[i];
    var statusID = e.getAttribute('data-object-id');
    if ($.inArray(statusID, banIds) !== -1) {
      e.remove();
    }
  }
}
```

What's the problem? And how do I solve it ?

Comment: Open console and take a look at errors.

Comment: I don't see where you set 'banIds'

Comment: The problem is that `document.getElementsByClassName(...)` returns HTMLCollection - array like object, but not an array ... So it is updated dynamically while you are deleting your elements.

Comment: @BogdanSavluk, then How should I fix this? Using jquery instead?

Comment: @cqcn1991: check the answers then. There is one that proposes tiny jquery-based solution

Comment: @cqcn1991, both answers below are good - but jquery one by zerkms is better(imho)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as jQuery is acceptable there is no reason to not use its facilities:

```
function toggle_visibility(className) {
    $('.' + className).filter(function() {
        return $.inArray($(this).data('object-id'), banIds) !== -1;
    }).remove();
}
```

Comment: @cqcn1991: why did you change my code to use `.each()`? http://jsfiddle.net/6D6Ly/1/ - this is the code that works

Comment: I'm not quite familiar with `filter`, so I change to `each` making it easier to understand for me. But I'm not sure I get it right.

Answer (score 2):

Use `while` cycle for delete. `For` cycle skips elements, because they already deleted and other elements have another position index in array.

Or write like this:

```
if ($.inArray(statusID, banIds) !== -1) {
    e.remove();
    i--;
}
```

And don't use `n`, because `elements.length` changes in cycle.

Answer (score 0):

This is typical error when deleting elements from indexed list.
You are missing fact that when element is deleted all elements after deleted are shifted in `index` to `index-1`. So the next element receives same index as deleted one but for loop still increments index and skips one element after deleted. 
 Simplest way to avoid this problem is to run loop backward:

```
  for (var i = n-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var e = elements[i];
    var statusID = e.getAttribute('data-object-id');
    if ($.inArray(statusID, banIds) !== -1) {
      e.remove();
    }
```